# Convert string to type geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in table with type string in the following format `53.57993, -1.7761`.

How could I modify it to type geography?

Comment: You are giving us data which would correspond to a point (presumably latitude and longitude).  Which geometry shape do you have in mind here?

Comment: "type":"Point" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
declare @instr varchar(20) ='53.57993, -1.7761';
DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',replace(@instr, ',', ''),')'), 4326);
print @g.ToString()
```

Comment: I got error System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

Comment: I tried this, It is working. may be it seems that it is related with your values

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```
DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(53.57993 -1.7761)', 4326);  
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
POINT (53.57993 -1.7761)
```

OR:

```
 SELECT @g
```

OUTPUT:

```
0xE6100000010C42CF66D5E76AFCBF11FC6F253BCA4A40
```

Comment: may be [No improvement along this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017#examples)